# Thymleaf escape quotes for HTML template

Tags: java, templates, thymeleaf

Is it possible to escape quotes for HTML templates in Thymleaf?

When generating HTML files for an Angular application, Thymleaf is using the Unicode value for a quoate `&#39;` istead of using the UTF-8 character.

For example:
The Thymleaf template is the following:

```java
<my-component th:fragment="componentField (field)" th:[colors]="${field.colors}"></my-component>
```

**Expected** -
The expected result is:

```html
<my-component [colors]="[{ type: 'RED'}]"></my-component>
```

**Actual** -
The actual result is:

```html
<my-component [colors]="[{ type: &#39;RED&#39;}]"></my-component>
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible... does Angular not work with `&#39;`?